# Converting value of text field to negative if checkbox is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have 10 text fields for numeric values. For each there is one checkbox. If the checkbox is checked then the value entered in the text field must get converted to a negative value and then be save in the database. If checked again it should become positive.

```
<td><input type="text" name="or" class="num" maxlength="5" ?>" id="or"/>db</td>
<td><input type="text" name="or2" class="num" maxlength="5" />db</td>
<td><input type="text" name="or4" class="num" maxlength="5" />db</td>
<td><input type="text" name="or8" class="num" maxlength="5" />db</td>
<td><input type="text" name="or5" class="num" maxlength="5" />db</td>
```

checkboxes for each text box

```
<td>-<input type="checkbox" name="orneg1 " class="check1" id="org"  /></td>
<td>-<input type="checkbox" name="org2" class="check2" /></td>
<td>-<input type="checkbox" name="org4" class="check3" /></td>
<td>-<input type="checkbox" name="org8" class="check4" /></td>
<td>-<input type="checkbox" name="org5" class="check5" /></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i){
   if ($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked') {
       var inputText  = $('input[type=text]:eq('+i+')');
       var inputValue = parseInt(inputText.val(),10);
       if (inputValue > 0) {
           inputValue = '-'+inputValue;
       } else {
           inputValue = (-1) * inputValue;
       }
       inputText.attr('value', inputValue);
   } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. i will try and let you know Thank you for your prompt reply

Answer (score 0):

You have two different things here :

- First, you want to add a behaviour on your onClick on the checkbox. Using jQuery it should be no problem to handle this. In the onClick clabback, you'll simply set the value of related input text to -value if the checkbox is checked. Else you'll set it to abs(value)
- Then you are talking about saving the satte in the database. For that you will need to use an ajax call transporting the input values as key/value pairs to the server.

I guess you can handle the code by yourself now that you know what to do :)

Answer (score 0):

**Working sample demo** http://jsfiddle.net/SQSMK/

I will recommend to look into Jquery `isNan` and `isNumeric` api's as well,

rest this demo should help: `:)`

P.s. - I hope you have `table` and `tr` tags which I have put in html below with minor tweaks.

**code**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

        $('input[type="text"][name="' + $(this).prop('name') + '"]').val(-$('input[type="text"][name="' + $(this).prop('name') + '"]').val());

    } else {
        $('input[type="text"][name="' + $(this).prop('name') + '"]').val(-parseInt($('input[type="text"][name="' + $(this).prop('name') + '"]').val()));
    }
});​
```

**html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
<td><input type="text" name="or1" class="num" maxlength="5" id="or"/>db</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="or2" class="num" maxlength="5" />db</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="or4" class="num" maxlength="5" />db</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="or8" class="num" maxlength="5" />db</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="or5" class="num" maxlength="5" />db</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td>-<input type="checkbox" name="or1" class="check1" id="org"/></td>
                    <td>-<input type="checkbox" name="or2" class="check2"  /></td>
                    <td>-<input type="checkbox" name="or3" class="check3"  /></td>
                    <td>-<input type="checkbox" name="or8" class="check4" /></td>
                    <td>-<input type="checkbox" name="or5" class="check5" /></td>
    </tr>
</table​
```